# Javascript: Loop Through Dynamically Generated Titles and Trunicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these titles that are dynamically generated on the server side of the app, and I would like to truncate them accordingly.

The snippet for generating the titles is:

```
 <p class="prod-title">{{ product.title }}</p>
```

The above generated an HTML code as:

```
<p class="prod-title"> Title 1 </p>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 2 </p>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 3 </p>
```

How can I truncate the generated titles based on a class using Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the elements and use [**`substring()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to truncate the string:

```js
$('.prod-title').each(function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var elText = el.text().trim();
  el.text(elText.substring(0, elText.length - 3));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 1 </p>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 2 </p>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 3 </p>
```

**OR:** You can use [**`slice()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
$('.prod-title').each(function(){
  var el = $(this);
  var elText = el.text().trim();
  el.text(elText.slice(0, elText.length - 3));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 1 </p>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 2 </p>
<p class="prod-title"> Title 3 </p>
```

Comment: I am not trying to remove an element. I am trying to truncate the output by 3 characters - say. So the output - respectively - would be titl for first paragraph, titl for second and titl for third. Thanks!

Comment: @Zeusox, I have updated the answer, please check:)